# Live Tile updates

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How do you create a live tile for Windows Phone 7?  I was wondering because I would basically like to have text that updates on the live tile once per 1-5 minutes that a user could just glance at.  Would this timing be possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To update the tile you can use a [push Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558(VS.92).aspx) or [ShellTileSchedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltileschedule(v=VS.92).aspx).

The level of frequency you are talking about is technically possible with puch notifications but not with a schedule. The highest [frequency you can use for a Schedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.updateinterval(v=VS.92).aspx) is hourly.

I would seriously recommend reviewing updating at the frequency level you are talking about though.

- Is the data really going to update that often?
- Is the user realisitically going to be checking their phone that often?

If you need to update the user quickly when data changes their are alternatives which are probably better suited. e.g. SMS, email, automated call or toast notification.

You should also consider updating less frequently. People don't check their phone that often 24 hours a day. Would it be very serious if the data a user saw was an hour old?

Comment: I would like to update financial quotes displayed on the tile every 5 minutes. It's easier to monitor this way than having to start an app over and over. It's unfortunate that there is no way to do this.

Comment: @Adal You can do this with notifications but it's not somethign I'd recommend. There are porbably more appropriate ways of monitoring stock prices if that frequency of update is important to you (your users).

Comment: Yes the information I need to display does get updated that often, in fact it gets updated every 30 seconds and I have a -maximum- of 5 minutes.

Comment: What really? ShellTileSchedule is only once per hour? That sounds like an arbitrary MS gimping of a cool feature. As a USER I can see several things that I would like to update atleast every 5 minutes, so I am with Chad.

Comment: It's very rare that you'd need something updated every few minutes 24 hours a day. (Yes, schedules don't have a social hours feature or anything like that.) This also highlights the importance of considering resources (particuarly battery life and network resources and data costs). The consequences of making a network connection to download a new image every 5 minutes will soon add up. It's very rare that users will need to always know the updated info every time it updates.

Comment: Which is why I would much rather not have to use push notifications but it looks like if 5 minutes is what I want it's my only option.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great article here:
http://chriskoenig.net/2010/08/16/customizing-wp7-push-notification-tiles/

Comment: This article only talks about using Tile Notifications but that isn't the only way to do it. The questions was also about whether the desided timings/frequency were possible.

Comment: Good point Matt.  Hopefully our combined answers will do the trick!  As far as frequency goes, if you are using push notifications in response to data changes then that frequency should be fine.  I would still recommend providing some settings to help modulate the frequency though.  The pushes are small, but the user's data plan should still be respected.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can do this as Matt advises. You should be aware of the related app cert reqt, and if in doubt, follow up with Microsoft directly if your usage would be considered "excessive".

**From the App Cert Reqts:**
2.13.2 The application and its use of the PNS must not excessively use network capacity or bandwidth of the PNS or otherwise unduly burden a Windows Phone or other Microsoft device or service with excessive push notifications, as determined by Microsoft in its reasonable discretion, and must not harm or interfere with any

Within that constraint, it's really a matter of how much bandwidth you want to use from your server sending out the notices and how much bandwidth the user wants to consume from their phone's data plan.

On the last point, I would recommend making the frequency of updates user configurable down to whatever maximium you decide is appropriate.