# How often will live tile update in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to update the live tile once a minute or at least once in 5 minutes with a new text data on the tile and on the secondary tile?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186630/live-tile-updates

Comment: @M.Mimpen not really, no info about background task or background audio agent.

Comment: It does comment on the exact same question IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal update rate is once per 30 min via background agent. Other methods are not precise (tile notifications) or mostly hacks. You can also update Live tile from a fake [background audio agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550858/updating-live-tiles-from-backgroud-audio-agent), but it can be treated as rule breaking by reviewer.